# Symfony 5 / Doctrine: Sorting entity collection by creation DateTime

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, repository, symfony5

I am developing a project using Symfony 5. One of my use-cases involves reading a collection from the Database, with the items sorted by creation order, descending (newest first). I am using the "Timestampable" extension from "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle" to save the createdAt and updatedAt timestamps in my entity.

According to Doctrine documentation, I can sort items ussing the Repository methods:

```
$sortedEntities = $repository->findBy(array('createdAt' => 'DESC'));
```

This is the attribute in question:

```
    /**
     * @var \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;
```

However, using 'ASC' or 'DESC' seems to have no impact on the ordering of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not reading [the documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/working-with-objects.html) correctly. The orderBy is the *second* argument, not the first.
The example given in the docs is

```
$tenUsers = $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')->findBy(array('age' => 20), array('name' => 'ASC'), 10, 0);
```

Here, you can see the orderBy (name, ASC) is the second arg. The first arg is a `where` arg - in this case, `WHERE age = 20`.

Here is the [full signature](https://github.com/doctrine/persistence/blob/2.2.x/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/ObjectRepository.php) from `Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectRepository`

```
/**
 * Finds objects by a set of criteria.
 *
 * Optionally sorting and limiting details can be passed. An implementation may throw
 * an UnexpectedValueException if certain values of the sorting or limiting details are
 * not supported.
 *
 * @param array<string, mixed> $criteria
 * @param string[]|null        $orderBy
 * @param int|null             $limit
 * @param int|null             $offset
 * @psalm-param array<string, 'asc'|'desc'|'ASC'|'DESC'> $orderBy
 *
 * @return object[] The objects.
 * @psalm-return T[]
 *
 * @throws UnexpectedValueException
 */
public function findBy(array $criteria, ?array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null);
```

I hope that clarifies it for you. :-)

[EDIT] In response to your comment, you cannot use `true` as a value for the first argument. Look at the signature I posted. The first argument is `@param array<string, mixed>`, so it needs an array. Try this then:

```
sortedEntities = $repository->findBy(array(), array('createdAt' => 'DESC'));
```

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, when I add the $criteria argument (which I don't always need, I guess there is a way to set it to true or other value that selects all fields), the behaviour is the same, order is not affected

Comment: @MaxPower I added more explanation and gave you the specific answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I passed an empty array and still wasn't working - then I realized that my controller methods were not ordered properly so the function was never actually called.
Many thanks for taking the time to respond and help me understand this method better :D